# When is the product of a diagonal matrix and a symmetric matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

A diagonal matrix and a symmetric matrix commute if their product is itself a symmetric matrix and vice versa (see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697991/do-diagonal-matrices-always-commute)). Are there other conditions that make their product symmetric?

Answer (score 7):

If the entries of the diagonal matrix are distinct, then it commutes with a symmetric matrix if and only if that matrix is diagonal.

More generally, if the diagonal matrix has the form
$$
D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 I_{k_1}\\&\lambda_2 I_{k_2} \\ && \ddots \\ &&& \lambda_m I_{k_m}}
$$
where $I_k$ denotes the $k \times k$ identity matrix, then a (symmetric) matrix $A$ will commute with $D$ if and only if $A$ is conformally block diagonal, which is to say that
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_1 \\ & A_2 \\ & & \ddots \\ &&& A_m}
$$
Where for each $j$, $A_j$ is a (symmetric) matrix of size $k_j \times k_j$.

Comment: When A is symmetric, $A_j$ is also symmetric, right?

Answer (score 1):

The only diagonal matrices such that their product with *every* symmetric matrix is again symmetric are the multiples of the identity matrix.

Comment: I am not interested in the product with every symmetric matrix. Only the special cases when this occurs.